# Rename multiple .txt files changing some characters in specific positions

Tags: command-line, bash, files, batch-rename

I have a collections of hundreds of **.txt** files in the same folder in Ubuntu 16.04, and they're named with strings and index numbers, like that:

```
a01_s01_e01_skeleton.txt
a01_s01_e02_skeleton.txt
a01_s01_e03_skeleton.txt
a01_s02_e01_skeleton.txt
...
a20_s10_e02_skeleton.txt
...
```

I must remove the **0** (zeros) from **every** .txt file where the number is smaller than 10, so in the end I'll have:

```
instead of : a01_s01_e01_skeleton.txt 

it will be: a1_s1_e1_skeleton.txt #notice that the 0s are gone.
```

**EDIT**

The position of the numbers is always the same, like in the examples. The files have a logic of order, so the renaming process must be totally correct.

How could I do that using the command line?

Comment: Useful additional info would be if the position of the numbers in the string is always the same or not, and if possible dupes might occur after renaming. If so, what do do then.

Comment: The position of the numbers in the string is always the same.

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself? Or are you expecting us to write this for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, just for fun, no doubt there are shorter cli solutions, but in python, the script below does the job *if* the directory is "flat" (as you say) *and* all files in it are valid files to rename. If not, we need to add an exception, so here we go:

```py
import shutil
import sys
import os

dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    sections = f.split("_")
    newname = "_".join(
        [s[0] + str(int(s[1:])) for s in sections[:3]] + [sections[-1]]
    )
    shutil.move(os.path.join(dr, f), os.path.join(dr, newname))
```

#### To use:

- Copy the code into an empty file, save it as `rename_stuff.py`
- Run it with the directory as argument:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/rename_stuff.py </directory/with/files>
  ```

As always, first try on a sample directory.

#### Explanation

- Read the files in the directory:

  ```
  for f in os.listdir(dr):
  ```
- Split the name by "_":

  ```
  sections = f.split("_")
  ```
- On the first three sections, replace the two (or more) -digit number by its int- ("real") value, so 01 -> 1, 10 -> 10, 020 -> 20, 000300 -> 300 and so on.
- Subsequently, glue the sections together again:

  ```
  newname = "_".join(
      [s[0] + str(int(s[1:])) for s in sections[:3]] + [sections[-1]]
  )
  ```

Answer (score 8):

With the perl `rename`, you can remove zeroes that occur between a non-digit and a digit.

```
$ touch a01_s01_e01_skeleton.txt a01_s01_e02_skeleton.txt a01_s01_e03_skeleton.txt a01_s02_e01_skeleton.txt a20_s10_e02_skeleton.txt
$ rename -n 's/(?<=\D)0+(?=\d)//g' *.txt
rename(a01_s01_e01_skeleton.txt, a1_s1_e1_skeleton.txt)
rename(a01_s01_e02_skeleton.txt, a1_s1_e2_skeleton.txt)
rename(a01_s01_e03_skeleton.txt, a1_s1_e3_skeleton.txt)
rename(a01_s02_e01_skeleton.txt, a1_s2_e1_skeleton.txt)
rename(a20_s10_e02_skeleton.txt, a20_s10_e2_skeleton.txt)
```

---

`rename` may or may not be the perl version. On my system it is called [`file-rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html) and it has an alternatives symlink as `/usr/bin/rename`

Answer (score 5):

### Shellscript

Using `rename` alias `rename.ul` installed from the package util-linux, I made the following bash shellscript, that I think can do the job for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

#####################


doer () {

# removes "0" from the string "{parameter}0"
# for example a0 --> a

 rename "s/${1}0/$1/" *
}
#####################

# main

#####################

doer a
doer s
doer e
```

Let us call the shellscript `renamer` and give it execute permissions.

If zeros to be removed are preceded by other letters than a,s,e, please add a call of `doer` with those letters into the script and modify the shellscript, if there are instances, not shown by your sample file names, which need more details in the substitute specification (the function `doer`).

### Test

Create and check 'original' files

```
$ touch a01_s01_e01_skeleton.txt a01_s01_e02_skeleton.txt a01_s01_e03_skeleton.txt a01_s02_e01_skeleton.txt a20_s10_e02_skeleton.txt
$ ls -1
a01_s01_e01_skeleton.txt
a01_s01_e02_skeleton.txt
a01_s01_e03_skeleton.txt
a01_s02_e01_skeleton.txt
a20_s10_e02_skeleton.txt
renamer
```

Run the shellscript

```
$ ./renamer
```

Check the result

```
$ ls -1
a1_s1_e1_skeleton.txt
a1_s1_e2_skeleton.txt
a1_s1_e3_skeleton.txt
a1_s2_e1_skeleton.txt
a20_s10_e2_skeleton.txt
renamer
$
```

Comment: why not change your regex to include all your alpha arguments and only run the function once (without any arguments)? Or better yet, just skip defining the function. `rename "s/[ase]0/$1/" *` all by itself does the trick.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, The command that you suggest does not work for me. I could change my regex to something more complicated or difficult to understand, but if my current script solves the problem of the OP, why make it more complicated? (There is no indication from the OP yet, which answer is preferred for the real case.)

Comment: Sorry I missed that you were also using the argument on the right hand side. You could simply change the whole thing to use capture groups.

Comment: Sorry in advance, but I've never worked with **shellscript** bash files before, and I'm confused about where to save the **rename.ul** file and how to make it run through the command line.

Comment: @ElisaMariaAlves, `rename` alias `rename-ul` comes with the package util-linux, which is normally installed by default in Ubuntu. So you need not worry about installing it. I mentioned it because there are other `rename` programs, that might work differently. So it runs when called (by the command line with it) as described in my answer. -- But I understand that you prefer another answer, which is OK for me. That answer is a good one. -- Good luck :-)

Comment: I've teste all the answers, and I learned something new with yours anyway, so thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ElisaMariaAlves, Did it work for you? Or did it fail somehow for some file names that exist in the real set of files?

Comment: It worked fine,

Answer (score 2):

Perl's rename utility is the best option for this, I think.

```
rename 's/(\w)0(\d)/$1$2/g' *.txt
```

This command will replace all occurrences of a letter followed by a zero followed by a digit, retaining the letter and the digit while discarding the zero, for every text file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using **[zsh](https://www.zsh.org/)**:

```
autoload zmv
zmv 'a(<->)_s(<->)_e(<->)_skeleton.txt' 'a${1#0}_s${2#0}_e${3#0}_skeleton.txt'
```

Comment: I do not get it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu **:-)** Please [edit] your answer and provide a bit more information on how your command works as a ton of people don't get it (bash is the standard) and then your  answer is likely to be deleted because of "low quality"  even though it's 100% correct. **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Answer (score 1):

[per this](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-rename-multiple-files-at-once-in-linux/) you can use mmv ,first install

```
 $ sudo apt-get install mmv
```

then use this

```
 mmv \*.txt \#1.text
```

rename all txt file to text file i hope it help you